# How to do calculation on two different values in same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to calculate time difference between two values in a single column in SQL server, please see below my use case.

Source table

```
ID  Original_Request_ID Audit_Date  key_c   value_c
115 1000000000006       1512401076  Status  In Progress  (2)
817 1000000000006       1515405051  Status  Assigned  (1)
827 1000000000006       1516099637  Status  In Progress  (2)
831 1000000000006       1516257920  Status  Resolved  (4)
```

Audit date stores the epoch value of the event date. 
as you see how status is changed from In Progress  (2) to assigned so i want to add a new column lets say "TimeTaken" which will have date diff of audit date.
so the value of TimeTaken for ID 115 =Audit_Date of Assigned Status where id is 817 minus Audit Date of id 115 = 1515405051 - 1512401076

Can someone please suggest a approach to do it.
I am using SQL Server 2012.

Expected Output

```
ID  Original_Request_ID Audit_Date     key_c      value_c           TimeTaken 
115 INC000000000006    1512401076      Status     In Progress  (2)   3003975
817 INC000000000006    1515405051      Status     Assigned  (1)      694586
827 INC000000000006    1516099637      Status     In Progress  (2)   158283
831 INC000000000006    1516257920      Status     Resolved  (4)
```

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LEAD` function for that:

```
SELECT *, LEAD(Audit_Date, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY Audit_Date) AS Next_Audit_Date
```

Which gives you:

```
| ID  | Original_Request_ID | Audit_Date | key_c  | value_c     | Next_Audit_Date |            |
|-----|---------------------|------------|--------|-------------|-----------------|------------|
| 115 | 1000000000006       | 1512401076 | Status | In Progress | (2)             | 1515405051 |
| 817 | 1000000000006       | 1515405051 | Status | Assigned    | (1)             | 1516099637 |
| 827 | 1000000000006       | 1516099637 | Status | In Progress | (2)             | 1516257920 |
| 831 | 1000000000006       | 1516257920 | Status | Resolved    | (4)             | NULL       |
```

And than calculate the difference.

Comment: You may need a partition in your call to `LAG` as well...depending on what the OP says.

Comment: You should use LEAD not LAG

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*
    , Audit_Date - LEAD(Audit_Date) OVER (
        PARTITION BY Original_Request_ID ORDER BY Id
        )
FROM myTable t
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.